# how to check the violation of the foreign key Sqlite

Tags: database, sqlite, database-design, foreign-keys, relational-database

I have two Tables, the first one is :

```
CREATE TABLE `Material_Type` (
    `Material_Type_ID`  integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `Material_Type` nvarchar NOT NULL,
    `Material_Type_Description` nvarchar
);
```

and the second Table is :

```
CREATE TABLE `Material` (
    `Material_ID`   integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `Material_Name` nvarchar NOT NULL,
    `Material_Description`  nvarchar,
    `Material_Picture`  BLOB,
    `Material_Type_ID`  integer NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(`Material_Type_ID`) REFERENCES `Material_Type`(`Material_Type_ID`)
);
```

[image]

My problem is that when I Insert a Material_Type_ID to the Material Table, Sqlite doesn't check the violation of the foreign key.
for example I have

Material_Type_ID    Material_Type     Material_Descriptio
1                   first material    first description
2                   2nd Mmaterial     2nd description

when I insert 20 in Material(Material_Type_ID) that doesn't generate any error.
I set `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON`;but nothing changed 
can you help me to set this verification please ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry I mean ON, I'd just corrected it

Comment: what is printed when you run `PRAGMA foreign_keys` ?

Comment: thanks wero for you answer, nothing happend , even when I insert a string into a integer cell, I receive no error message

Comment: maybe your sqlite version is too old or was compiled without foreign key support, see http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable

Comment: version 3.8, it the lastest one

Comment: Show the code that opens the DB, executes the PRAGMA, and executes the INSERT.

Comment: Thanks CL for your answer, but I have only this code and I executed the Pragma separately. (I have of course other Tables conneted with each others with the same problem if you could help me with this I'm gonna apply the solution for the rest)